# fonts worked on local host but not on live server

Tags: css, fonts

I saved playball-regular.ttf file in font folder. it is working on local host, but same file index.php and font folder and css is copied in the live server, it does not work.

Comment: you should always put in mind to use `relative path` not `absolute path` when it comes to includes, such as font, images etc.

Comment: Can you show me your CSS code!

Answer (score 0):

I would bet the path in your CSS file to your font file is incorrect for the live server.